# Storyboard changes won't update when running my app

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios-simulator, xcode7

I've made some changes on my storyboard,like changing the constraints, moving buttons and labels around but none of the changes seem to update when I build and run my app. It's showing the older version of my app.

Anyone know the possible reason for this and how this could be fixed?

Comment: Sometimes doing a clean fixes issues like this. Or, go to Preferences->Locations->DerivedData and delete the derived data folder. If all else fails, remove the app from the device and reinstall.

Comment: Sounds like an Xcode bug, have you tried restarting Xcode or a clean on the project?

Answer (score 0):

if you changes in storyboard only with constraints maybe you forgot apply you changes

1)
[image]

2)
[image]